# Disable Google Chrome Frame Inspector

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

It is really quick one.

I have decided to write this post to finally (I wish) found the answer if there is an option to disable this feature on Google Chrome Inspector:

[image: Google Chrome Frame Inspector]

It is just driving me mad when I am trying to click some element on my DOM structure and then, surprisedly the tool finally loaded this Frame and everything just jumping! It is the same level of being annoying like loved by every one lazy load advertisements.

Please, anyone, if you can help me, please do!

Comment: What feature? Your screenshot is unclear as to what you're talking about.

Comment: let me edit this one!

Comment: I still don't know what you're referring to. My Chrome inspector doesn't tend to be "jumping" around when I use it. Can you link us to a page and instructions to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @ceejayoz thank you for your patience. As you can see I have not many experiences on posting there.

I understand it is happening when some script is loading asynchronusly on web page.

Take a look on there as an example:

https://careerinteractive.org/services/coaching-programmes

Comment: This should be fixed in Chrome Canary, which you can install separately.

Comment: I experience this myself and it's super irritating.